# Is $elemMatch useful on arrays that does not contain subdocs?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to get a grip on the `$elemMatch` operator and it seems it's only useful for arrays of subdocuments. Is it the case or am I misunderstanding the operator?

If I have 3 documents containing dimensions as follows :

```
{_id:1,dimensions:[1,2,3]},
{_id:1,dimensions:[3,4,5]},
{_id:1,dimensions:[6,7,8]}
```

I thought I'd get different results if I used the following queries :

```
db.collection.find({dimensions:{$gte:1,$lte:3}})
db.collection.find({dimensions:$elemMatch{$gte:1,$lte:3}})
```

Thanks

Comment: You will get same result for both the queries but the second one is more precise

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet How so?